# Informix XA Driver in Play! Framework application

Tags: hibernate, informix, playframework

I am trying to use Informix database with a Play! Framework application. I am new to Informix.

I have Informix 11.70 installed on my windows machine and I am running Play 1.1.

In Play! you can specify your db connections like this:

```
db.url=jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9088/mydatabase:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_informix1170
db.driver=com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
db.user=informix
db.pass=password
```

I get an exception however in running my Play! app:

```
An unexpected error occured caused by exception PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:153)
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:195)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1245)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.startTx(JPAPlugin.java:321)
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.beforeInvocation(JPAPlugin.java:289)
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.before(Invoker.java:116)
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:186)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Transactions not supported
        at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setAutoCommit(IfxSqliConnect.java:2189)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:91)
        ... 7 more
```

I think because I am trying to execute my query within a transaction but I haven't specified an XA driver. Only com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver. However I can't seem to find the XA driver to use for Informix.

How can I configure my Play! application to use Informix?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't properly configured Informix. Your database is not configured for transaction logging, and so, it doesn't supports transactions. Not really a Hibernate nor Play! problem. So, recreate your table with something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase WITH LOG;
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ddi73.htm